# Debug Office add-in in VS code

Tags: excel, typescript, office-js, office-addins, excel-web-addins

Beginner in Office add-ins and VS code here...

I followed the steps from [this MS tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/excel-tutorial-create-custom-functions?tabs=excel-windows) on creating an Excel custom functions add-in. Because I want to debug it using VS code, I had to create an Excel Custom Functions Add-in project option in the Yeoman generator, with TypeScript selected as the script type (according to MS).

The add-in works fine, but the related [debugging tutorial from MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-debugging#use-the-vs-code-debugger-for-excel-desktop) doesn't seem to work. Any breakpoint added appears as unbound, plus there's a "read source map" error, which might be related (see screenshot).

Any ideas how can I make this working?

Thank you for your time,

Adrian

Edit: this is the content of launch.json, I didn't change what Yeoman generated.

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Excel Desktop (Custom Functions)",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 9229,
      "timeout": 600000,
      "preLaunchTask": "Debug: Excel Desktop",
      "postDebugTask": "Stop Debug",
      "resolveSourceMapLocations": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Excel Desktop (Edge Chromium)",
      "type": "pwa-msedge",
      "request": "attach",
      "useWebView": true,
      "port": 9229,
      "timeout": 600000,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "preLaunchTask": "Debug: Excel Desktop",
      "postDebugTask": "Stop Debug"
    },
    {
      "name": "Excel Desktop (Edge Legacy)",
      "type": "office-addin",
      "request": "attach",
      "url": "https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html?_host_Info=Excel$Win32$16.01$en-US$$$$0",
      "port": 9222,
      "timeout": 600000,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "preLaunchTask": "Debug: Excel Desktop",
      "postDebugTask": "Stop Debug"
    },
    {
      "name": "Office Online (Chrome)",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      // To debug your Add-in:
      // 1. When prompted, enter the url (share link) to an Office Online document.
      // 2. Sideload your Add-in. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/sideload-office-add-ins-for-testing
      "url": "${input:officeOnlineDocumentUrl}",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "preLaunchTask": "Debug: Web"
    },
    {
      "name": "Office Online (Edge Chromium)",
      "type": "pwa-msedge",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9222,
      // To debug your Add-in:
      // 1. When prompted, enter the url (share link) to an Office Online document.
      // 2. Sideload your Add-in. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/sideload-office-add-ins-for-testing
      "url": "${input:officeOnlineDocumentUrl}",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "preLaunchTask": "Debug: Web"
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "officeOnlineDocumentUrl",
      "type": "promptString",
      "description": "Please enter the url for the Office Online document."
    }
  ]
}
```

[image: error]

Comment: What is your launch condition?

Comment: Hi Eugene, thank you for your help! I added the content of launch.json.

Comment: What target did you choose from available options?

Comment: I recommend using Visual Studio 2017 personally FYI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VS Code to debug custom functions that don't use a shared runtime in Office Excel on the desktop. So, make sure that you don't use the shared runtime in the add-in.

To use VS Code with Microsoft Edge, you must install the [Microsoft Edge DevTools extension for Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/visual-studio-code/microsoft-edge-devtools-extension).

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, but according to the requirements mentioned in the above custom functions debugging tutorial: "A custom function that doesn't use a shared runtime is an Excel Custom Functions Add-in project created with the Yeoman generator for Office Add-ins.", which is exactly the project I created.. So I assume my project doesn't use a shared runtime.

Comment: What is your option from the launch.json file?

Comment: The first one: Excel Desktop (Custom Functions)

Comment: See [Debugger spams "Could not read sourcemaps" messages](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102042)